# how to add a simple button in RVIZ

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to add a button on rviz (in plugin format) that when I click on it, it publishes a Boolean message ROS informing the robot to light a led for example. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have an example of a plugin I made to publish a pose message on the map, but I need to interact with the mouse on the map. In that case I would like the message to be published as soon as I click on the button for the "light up led" plugin. Would it be possible to make this change?

setDock.cpp:

```
#ifndef SETDOCK_HPP
#define SETDOCK_HPP

#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN  // See: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-22829
#include <QObject>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "rviz/default_plugin/tools/pose_tool.h"
#endif


namespace rviz_plugin_setDock
{
    //class SetDock;


    class SetDock : public rviz::PoseTool
    {
      Q_OBJECT
    public:
      SetDock();
      //virtual ~SetDock();
      //virtual void onInitialize();

    protected:
      virtual void onPoseSet(double x, double y, double theta);

    public Q_SLOTS:
      void updateTopic();

    protected:
      ros::NodeHandle nh_;
      ros::Publisher pub_;
    
    };
}  // namespace rviz_plugin_setDock

#endif  // SETDOCK_HPP
```

setDock.cpp:

```
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.h>
#include "rviz/display_context.h"
#include "setDock/setDock.hpp"


namespace rviz_plugin_setDock
{
    SetDock::SetDock()
    {
      updateTopic();
    }

    void SetDock::updateTopic()
    {
      pub_ = nh_.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped>("dock_position", 1 );
    }

    void SetDock::onPoseSet(double x, double y, double theta)
    {
          std::string fixed_frame = context_->getFixedFrame().toStdString();
          geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped pose;
          pose.header.frame_id = fixed_frame;
          pose.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
          pose.pose.pose.position.x = x;
          pose.pose.pose.position.y = y;

          tf::Quaternion quat;
          quat.setRPY(0.0, 0.0, theta);
          tf::quaternionTFToMsg(quat,
                        pose.pose.pose.orientation);
          pub_.publish(pose);

    }

}  // namespace rviz_plugin_setDock

#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(rviz_plugin_setDock::SetDock, rviz::Tool)
```

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370870/how-to-add-a-simple-button-in-rviz/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2021-02-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-02**:
You could take a look at [InstitutMaupertuis/simple_rviz_plugin](https://gitlab.com/InstitutMaupertuis/simple_rviz_plugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used this example ([example](https://gitlab.acfr.usyd.edu.au/its/rviz-hmi/-/blob/master/src/hmi_panel.h)) and ended up creating a panel for what I needed. Gvdhoorn's comment is also valid.

---

Originally posted by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) with karma: 125 on 2021-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0